# Unable to locate libMailCore2-ios.a framework file when building MailCore2

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, mailcore2

I forked the Mailcore2 repo here: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/

and tried to build the libMailcore2-ios.a framework myself.

1. Clone the repo
2. Open up the mailcore2.xcodeproj file in build-mac
3. Select the mailcore ios target and try building with cmd+b
4. The build succeeds

However, I'm unable to find where this project file exports the libMailcore2-ios.a file. I see the linked products in the project, but they are all red.

Any help?

Comment: The usual ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData' directory ...

Comment: Thanks, I see the libMailCore2-ios.a file now. However, comparing my built product vs the pre-built one provided by MailCore2 here: http://d.etpan.org/mailcore2-deps/mailcore2-ios/

My product is 25MB and the one online is 115MB. How do I build the full version with the mailcore2.xcodeproj? @DinhViêtHoà

Comment: It's with all architectures enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I feel like an idiot but in the mailcore project, I see a build target framework for "mailcore ios" but it doesn't explicitly state any architectures under "Architecture" in the "Build Settings" tab. 

What's the process to build this framework to include all architectures? @DinhViêtHoà

Comment: See https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/scripts